# How to get steam avatar with steamworks in c#?

Tags: c#, avatar, steamworks-api

I'm programming in c# .NET **I'm not using Unity** and I want by means of steamworks collect and put player's avatar in picturebox. I did SOMETHING, but don't know what's next. I'm new in steamworks and I can't using it correctly.

```
var avatarInt = SteamFriends.GetMediumFriendAvatar(SteamUser.GetSteamID());
uint Width, Height;
SteamUtils.GetImageSize(avatarInt, out Width, out Height);
var abc_test = (SteamUser.GetSteamID().ToString());
byte[] avatarstream = new byte[4 * (int)Width * (int)Height];
SteamUtils.GetImageRGBA(avatarInt, avatarstream, 4 * (int)Width * (int)Height);
```

Earlier I  did something similar with player's nick.

```
nick_steam.Text = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();
```

Comment: what does GetImageRGA return?

Comment: GetImageRGA return true.

Answer (score 1):

From the Steamworks github:

https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET-Test/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/SteamUtilsTest.cs

```
public static Texture2D GetSteamImageAsTexture2D(int iImage) {
    Texture2D ret = null;
    uint ImageWidth;
    uint ImageHeight;
    bool bIsValid = SteamUtils.GetImageSize(iImage, out ImageWidth, out ImageHeight);

    if (bIsValid) {
        byte[] Image = new byte[ImageWidth * ImageHeight * 4];

        bIsValid = SteamUtils.GetImageRGBA(iImage, Image, (int)(ImageWidth * ImageHeight * 4));
        if (bIsValid) {
            ret = new Texture2D((int)ImageWidth, (int)ImageHeight, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, true);
            ret.LoadRawTextureData(Image);
            ret.Apply();
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: ok thx but i don't using Unity and i haven't got Texture2D function.

Comment: Not sure about it, but maybe you can adapt it to other Texture related classes, for example Direct3D https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb152994(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok but if i use Unity angine in visual studio, convert texture 2D to image is possible? Because i added Unity dedication for visual studio dll file and now I can use all Unity's functions.

Comment: Check if it is public `Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData` function code

Comment: I think I found a solution of my problem but I have to do  some code's modifications and then check if it works https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/494386-c---convert-texture2d-to-image/

Answer (score 0):

From your already existing code, I made this. To use it on a PictureBox you can just do:

`pictureBox.Image = avatarBitmap;`

```cs
var avatarInt = SteamFriends.GetMediumFriendAvatar(SteamUser.GetSteamID());
uint Width, Height;
SteamUtils.GetImageSize(avatarInt, out Width, out Height);

byte[] avatarStream = new byte[4 * (int)Width * (int)Height];
SteamUtils.GetImageRGBA(avatarInt, avatarStream, 4 * (int)Width * (int)Height);

// Create a Bitmap with the correct dimensions
Bitmap avatarBitmap = new Bitmap((int)Width, (int)Height);

// Lock the Bitmap data
BitmapData bmpData = avatarBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)Width, (int)Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

// Create a color array to store the corrected colors
byte[] colors = new byte[4];

// Copy and correct the image data
for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
    {
        int index = (y * (int)Width + x) * 4;

        colors[0] = avatarStream[index + 2]; // Red channel
        colors[1] = avatarStream[index + 1]; // Green channel
        colors[2] = avatarStream[index + 0]; // Blue channel
        colors[3] = avatarStream[index + 3]; // Alpha channel

        Marshal.Copy(colors, 0, (IntPtr)(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt64() + index), 4);
    }
}

// Unlock the Bitmap data
avatarBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```